# Powershell: Combine ContainerInherit and ObjectInherit in FileSystemAccessRule?

Tags: powershell, enums

I'm writing a script that should set filesystem access rights for a folder and all of it's contents.

To affect all content, both subfolders and files, one should combine ContainerInherit and ObjectInherit according to the .NET documentation. But I can't get that to work and I'm not sure about the syntax.

Sample code:

```
$ar = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user),FullControl,ContainerInherit,InheritOnly,Allow)
```

That'll work and so would using `ObjectInherit` only, but how can I combine them? Using quotation marks and a comma, like this `"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"` won't work, since it's appearantly not allowed to mix string and non-string argument.

I've also tried using the `-and` operator, but that just gives me an error. Assigning the enums to a variable (`$inherit = ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit`) won't work either.

So, any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can merge them using -bor (analogous to | in other languages). Parsing it from a string using a comma as shown in the other answer also works.

I also corrected your sample syntax and this sample should work.

```
$if=[Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]
$fsr=[Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]
$pf=[Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]
$flags = [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]($if::ContainerInherit -bor $if::ObjectInherit)

$ar = new-object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user)),$fsr::FullControl, $flags, $pf::InheritOnly, "Allow")
```

But even simpler is to use strings only:

```
new-object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($user, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "InheritOnly", "Allow")
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd already tried using strings only, but appearantly there was some other problem with my code, which made me think that strings only didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not in front of a computer but try this:

[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit'